# TextView truncating number in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm having trouble with setting a number into the text view, it only shows the first digit and truncates the rest. Example, if i set this string "12345" it only shows "1". Notice that if i hardcode that number in the setText method, it works, but when I set the number through Integer.toString, it doesn't. Also i made a Toast for debugging and the String it shows is the right one.

Here is my code for the Activity:

```
int inviteCount = inviteArray.size();
String inviteCountString = Integer.toString(inviteCount);
inviteCountTextView.setText(inviteCountString);
showToast(inviteCountString); 

protected void showToast(final String text) {
    //   Creates a Toast when there is an error
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(RootActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the code for the Layout File

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/inviteImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/friend_invitations_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inviteNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#88ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of the error. As you can see, the toast is showing a 10. But on the texfield which is at the top is only showing a 1. Again, if I write android:text="10" it shows correctly.

[image: Error]

Comment: it's an array list of invitations. It only returns the size of the list in this case.

Comment: And with the String.valueOf method?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `android:text="0"` part or replacing it with something bigger?

Comment: Hi! thanks for the responses.

I tried to put in the text init "000" and it shows them ok, until i change the value dynamically and get the same problem.

Also tried with String.valueOf with the same result

Comment: try `String inviteCountString = String.format("%d", inviteCount);`

Comment: can you try increasing framelayout's width?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks a lot for your suggestions, but none of them seemed to work... I added a screenshot to the post to better illustrate the issue. Any other ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: It seems to me that this may simply be a layout problem. I'm puzzled why it's initial value is setting the dimension correctly. I would suggest replacing the inefficient construction of the FrameLayout with just a TextView with a background. Perhaps to narrow down the problem, you can simplify the layout around that view.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I went with your suggestion and all is dandy now. If you want to make it into a proper answer I would mark it as correct.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma just wanted to remind you that if you make your suggestion into a proper answer, I can mark it as correct. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undoubtedly a layout problem. You can inspect your Layout Hierarchy using the ADT tool in Eclipse. Likely the `TextView`'s width is being clamped by `FrameLayout` measuring only its immediate child dimensions, namely that of the `ImageView`.

To be honest, I'm puzzled why it's initial value is setting the dimension correctly and why the dimensions aren't determined by *all* children.

I would suggest replacing the inefficient construction of the `FrameLayout` with just a `TextView` with a background. Perhaps to narrow down the problem, you can simplify the layout around that view.

For example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inviteNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="#88ffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:background="@drawable/friend_invitations_background" />
```